# How to find raw mongodb documents via mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find the raw documents via mongoose.

```
Model.collection.find({}, { skip : BATCH*pgi, limit : BATCH }, function(err, docs){
```

Here i was expecting docs to be raw mongodb documents.

But i am not getting so.

How to get raw documents as of above case?

Comment: You are using the `.collection()` accessor which means that there is no more Mongoose involvement. The problem here it that you are returning a "cursor", which is not the same as how the mongoose methods do it. They convert to an array by default.

Comment: But it does not have hasNext() funciton. Rather it has nextObject only. How can i iterate over the documents

Comment: That's because the `.collection` accessor and the subsequent `.find()` operation returns an Object that is consistent with the node native driver [`Cursor()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/cursor.html) interface. The only valid methods are those implemented there. This is not the MongoDB shell.

Comment: @Koka It's not clear what you're ultimately trying to do, but have you looked at using [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) instead of using the native driver?

Answer (score 5):

How about `Model.find({}).lean()`?

Answer (score 0):

Using toArray after cursor worked for me

```
Model.collection.find({}).skip(BATCH*pgi).limit(BATCH).toArray(function(err, docs){
});
```

Comment: but this seems very costly .. looking for a better answer